# SPI and GDO, what is GDO an acronym for?

Tags: hardware, spi, bus, acronym

In connection with a SPI bus there is typically a number of GDO pins used for interrupting the master or the slave of the SPI connection. But what is GDO an acronym for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General Digital Output

See for example http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2500.pdf.

Comment: I've looked through the document, and nowhere do I see the General prefix. It says Digital Output, but never actually General Digital Output. Otherwise I've missed something.

Comment: They do write "digital output pin for general use", and normally one would refer to these as GPIO for General Purpose I/O.

Comment: It seems that the term is rather TI specific though. I guess I'll just assume General Digital Output is the intented "backronym." Thanks.

Comment: Btw., the datasheet you are referencing is the exact device that I am working with. Quite a coincidence. ;)